# how to get the already selected value of dropdown protractor

Tags: protractor

I have a select tag with some options under it . I select one value out of those along with other field values and move to next page. Once I return to previous page I want to check whether the dropdown value is same as that I selected. How can I get the already selected value using protractor. Can someone please help.

Comment: Have a look at this, go to the end of article for solution - https://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/12/01/protractor-and-dropdowns-validation/

Comment: Please provide some HTML and your current attempt of solving this problem so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Following @Grasshopper's comment, I read [this](https://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/12/01/protractor-and-dropdowns-validation/), and the following worked for me:

```
expect(element(by.xxxxxx('xxxxxxx')).$('option:checked').getText()).toEqual('xxxxxx')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dropdownval=element(by.xpath/css("Xpathofdropdown/cssofdropdown")).element(by.css('option:checked')).getText();    
console.log(dropdownval);
```

Comment: Please provide a sentence for explanation of your solution and user proper code styling. Thanks.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code helps me to resolve the issue,now the variable contains the value of the dropdown selected

var dropdownval=element(by.xpath("XpathOfDropdown")).element(by.css('option:checked')).getText();
console.log(dropdownval);

Answer (score -1):

First select the input, then select the option using css, with the `option:selected` tag:

```
var selected = element(by.css('#ID_OF_THE_SELECT option:selected'))
```

Comment: Hi ,Thanks all.The below worked for me expect(element(by.id('id')).element(by.css('option:checked')).getText()).to.eventually.equal(value)

Comment: There is no :selected selector but there is :checked (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked ). You can also check for the presence of the selected *attribute*, using e.g. `element(by.css('#ID_OF_THE_SELECT option[selected]'))`